# Background of a div inside another one with "white-space: nowrap;" does not cover all the width

Tags: css, html, nowrap

Ok, I've got a problem out there. To be short, here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/2/). I'll repeat myself here:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="selected">
            <span>Why don't you cover all the width!?</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Little content</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #0f0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 200px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #f00;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The first question is: why does not the inner `div`'s background cover the entire `span`?
The second one: I'd like to have a fix, of course.

And one more thing: the html elements are generated by a third-party tool, to which I have no access, which makes "wrapping it all in another div" thing impossible. Only CSS, only hardcore!

UPDATE:

By the way, the container is itself resizable (a `frame` inside a `frameset` to be precise).

EDIT:

I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/7/) in order to provide more info. The problem is, that when the second `div` will be selected, I'd like the red background to stretch to the width of the longest line.

UPDATE 2:

The above described problem can be solved with `display: table-row;` (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/15/)). The tricky thing is to make this work even if content is less wide than the container itself ([a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/16/)).

Comment: It's a frame? Why didn't you just say so? OK, I updated my answer, again, but next time please try to find out what the problem is before posting about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divs have `width:auto` by default. So the inner div is 100px wide, like the outer one. The span overflows out of the div.

In this particular case, the easiest solution is to give the inner div display:inline-block

```
div div {display:inline-block}
```

so that it no longer fits itself in its parent, but it moulds itself to the width of its contents.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/5/).

Edit: to answer your second question: yes, the display:inline-block stops the `selected` div from being as wide as the container.
Fortunately, that can be corrected by adding

```
min-width:100%;
```

in addition to the display:inline-block. See [more updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/11/).

Another edit:
And the question keeps changing. Now it's about frames in a frameset. Oh well.
[Here is the latest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/21/) that solves the problem as formulated now. But let's see what changes the future has in store...

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. Please, see my updated question.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. But you did change the whole question while we were answering. Such practices are frowned upon. Please don't do it again.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I was struggling with it for two hours and didn't think the problem was not described well enough

Comment: Oh, I see you change the question again; you want the selected div to be as wide as the longest line. Hm. Must think.

Comment: @MrLister I've been thinking too and I'm a bit stuck on how to get the  selected div to be as wide as it's sibling (without making the parent bigger)

Comment: @SLoW, that is probably done with `display: table-row;` (see Update 2)

Comment: @MrLister wow, that is just magic. My apologies to you and the entire community for the continuous question edits.

Comment: @Dethariel And my apologies for the irritated reaction, but I was getting frustrated and actually waiting for you to say "but that won't work in the _real_ situation" again. So, sorry, and glad it's been solved!

Comment: @MrLister Actually, one of my co-workers proposed an alternative solution using `:after` pseudo-element. You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/92y3n/3/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to apply the background color to the span instead of the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="selected">
        <span>Why don't you cover all the width!?</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Little content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #0f0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 200px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #f00;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I updated my fiddle and answer, like @Mr Lister said, you need to add `display:inline-block`

Comment: As seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/9/), when the second div gets selected, I want it's background to also cover the full width of a container.

Comment: Adding `width:100%` sets the background of selected to 100px (which is the width of the container) is that what you want, or you want it to stretch to the width of the longest line?

Comment: I "want it to stretch to the width of the longest line"

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is because you have explicit width to the parent div. You can apply `display: inline-block` to inner div and remove the `width: 100px` from the parent.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="test">
        <span>Why don't you cover all the width!?</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
     background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/M294p/6/